# Alternative to Mac OS X codesign for signing binaries on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, code-signing, signing

We have a need to sign Mac OS X binaries on Linux. Is there a port or clone of the codesign tool that runs on Linux systems (ok if it is written in Java, Ruby, etc)?

We are looking at porting codesign tool ourselves or using something like [Darling](http://www.darlinghq.org/) emulation layer, but rather avoid it if at all possible

Edit: Basically I am looking for an equivalent of [OSSLSigncode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/) that allows signing Windows binaries on Linux

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732927/signed-executables-under-linux), that could be a duplicate for it. I thinks there's still no good solution for this, although there seems to be [some progress](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/1301.1/04326.html). Your best bet today is package level signing.

Comment: Thanks Javier, but those posts are for signing Linux executables on Linux. I need to sign OS X binaries on Linux using the same process codesign performs.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand you right, sorry. I'm clueless, then.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736368/how-to-sign-a-mac-os-x-application-in-linux) - unfortunately there's no way to do it on a linux machine.

Comment: Thanks @favoretti So far we have not been able to find anything, but it is just C++ code, so it must be possible to port. Just trying to figure out if somebody did it before as with Windows